# get 'Documents' path in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I understand you can probably use the following code to get the job done in most cases:

```
mydocpath = fullfile(getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Documents');
```

However, if the user has moved 'Doucments' folder to a different location, for example: `E:\Documents`, the above code won't work, since `getenv('USERPROFILE')` always returns `C:\Users\MY_USER_NAME`.

In C#, one can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`, which always returns the correct path regardless where 'Documents' is. Is there anything similar in Matlab?

---

My current solution is rather clumsy and probably unsafe:

```
% search in the MATLAB path lists
% this method assumes that there is always a path containing \Documents\MATLAB registered already
searchPtn = '\Documents\MATLAB';
pathList = strsplit(path,';');
strIdx = strfind(pathList, searchPtn);
candidateIdx = strIdx{find(cellfun(@isempty,strIdx)==0, 1)}(1);
myDocPath = pathList{candidateIdx}(1 : strIdx{candidateIdx}+ numel(searchPtn));
```

Comment: AFAIK, if it has been moved from `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` then the only way to get it programatically outside of the .NET approach you're already aware of is to get it from [the registry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx). You may be able to use the [.NET libraries with MATLAB directly](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html), but I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @excaza thanks for the idea of registry. I found a solution using `dos` instead of the .NET libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @excaza 's suggestion, I came up with a solution using [`dos`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html) and the cmd command found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1132288/windows-command-prompt-get-relocated-users-documents-folder) to query the registry.

```
% query the registry
[~,res]=dos('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Personal');
% parse result
res = strsplit(res, ' ');
myDocPath = strtrim(res{numel(res)});
```

---

**Edit:**

If the document folder in customer's PC has not been relocated or moved to one of the environment path such as %SYSTEMROOT%, the above method would return

```
%SOME_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%/Documents(Or a custom folder name)
```

The above path will not work in Matlab's functions such as mkdir or exist, which will take `%SOME_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%` as a folder name. Therefore we need to check for the existence of environment path in the return value and get the correct path:

```
[startidx, endidx] = regexp(myDocPath,'%[A-Z]+%');
if ~isempty(startidx)
    myDocPath = fullfile(getenv(myDocPath(startidx(1)+1:endidx(1)-1)), myDocPath(endidx(1)+1:end));
end
```

Full code:

```
% query the registry
[~,res]=dos('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Personal');
% parse result
res = strsplit(res, ' ');
% get path
myDocPath = strtrim(res{numel(res)});
% if it returns %AAAAA%/xxxx, meaning the Documents folder is
% in some environment path.
[startidx, endidx] = regexp(myDocPath,'%[A-Z]+%');
if ~isempty(startidx)
    myDocPath = fullfile(getenv(myDocPath(startidx(1)+1:endidx(1)-1)), myDocPath(endidx(1)+1:end));
end
```