# matlab global documents folder path

Tags: matlab, directory

In my matlab script I would like to output some files in a specific folder.
My function will accept a path to the desired folder and will check for its existance, but I would also like to implement a default behaviour consisting in saving everything in a default folder (named with day and time) located in the document folder of the computer.

Looking around I found some suggestion ([get 'Documents' path in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320764/get-documents-path-in-matlab)) on how to detect the correct folder in specific conditions (let's say a Windows PC, the default document folder, something with a specific name, ...). Is there anything more general, usable for all platforms (Win, Mac and Unix)? Or should I implement some switch?

Thanks.

Comment: This question could almost entirely be summed up with "is there a system-independent way to get the default documents path in MATLAB", the answer to which is [documented](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html#bvdi512-1) to be `userpath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making an answer out of [Wolfie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151443/matlab-global-documents-folder-path#comment89287675_51151443).

Directly taken from [Matlab documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html):

> `userpath('reset')` sets the first folder on the search path to the
>   default for your platform. The default userpath folder is
>   platform-specific.
>
> ```
> Windows® platforms — %USERPROFILE%/Documents/MATLAB.
>
> Mac platforms — $home/Documents/MATLAB.
>
> Linux® platforms — $home/Documents/MATLAB if $home/Documents exists.
> ```